Power automate integration with PowerApps - RunOnlyUser functionality not working
I have integrated a power automate in my Power Apps i.e. Canvas App.
Power automate flow generates a report using below connectors and send it to the user in email from specific user.
List of connectors:

Dataverse
Excel
OneDrive
Outlook

All above connectors uses the same account.
Canvas app has a button to generate the report on which it should execute the Power automate flow.
Issue?

When user tries to access application it gets popup for consent for the connectors. (Refer below images)


Considering few references, I even tried below approaches:

Share Flows as Run-Only Users When Trigger from PowerApps
Disable The Power Apps Permissions Pop-Up (Bypass Consent Form)



You need to understand the flowing things:

Whenever a user try to use the app,  "Allow Access" popup is not only asking for permission to use Power-automate connectors, but also for the connectors which are being used in PowerApps too.
The level of permissions which are being used by these connectors in PowerApps and Power-automate are different.

Hence, the popup which is being showed right now in PowerApps, are the only connector which are being used inside your PowerApp only not your Power-Automate flow.
Your flow is set accurately .

Thank you for your response. I am pretty sure I have NOT directly implemented Outlook and OneDrive in PowerApp. Those connectors are just used in the flow.

Oh okay, in order to verify you can check inside Data Tab in left panel of your PowerApps editor.

One more thing is if, these were connectors from Power-automate then all 4 mentioned connection reference permission would appear in the popup not just these two. I would recommend to check it via above mentioned way.

Yes, they do appeared - but as the user has license for Dataverse & Excel it automatically creates them. And as user do not have assigned licenses for OneDrive & Outlook it shows popup.

Na buddy, it doesn't works that's way. It doesn't matter whether you have licence or not, popup will be there

Just try refreshing your flow once, inside your and app and republish

Tried that already - not working either.
